# How to wrap a loop variable in an HTML tag

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through a list of teaching plans and create a <ul> with them.

The code below works but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this with jquery and the .wrap() or .wrapAll() function/s?

```
    for (const unit in themeList) {

        let lesson = themeList[unit];

        $('.card-body', themeCard).append('<li>' + lesson + '</li>');
    }

    $('li', themeCard).wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
```

I tried something like:

```
$('.card-body', themeCard).append(lesson).wrap('<li></li>')
```

But that just wraps the entire HTML contents in <li> tags.

Answer (score 0):

html is basically string type element. If you are doing js, you could have an algo to form a specific string and then append that string to a class that you want. examples like:

```
let output = ''
for (const unit in themeList) {
    let lesson = themeList[unit];
    output = '<ul>' + '<li>' + lesson '<li>' + '<ul>'
}
```

you will get a string like: `<ul><li>themeList[0]<li><ul><ul><li>themeList[1]<li><ul>....`
and then append this to your class/html/doc.

or if you want just one `ul` wrap everything:

```
let output = ''
for (const unit in themeList) {
    let lesson = themeList[unit];
    output = '<li>' + lesson '<li>'
}
output = '<ul>' + output + '<ul>'
```

or you could do `document.createElement()`

```
const para = document.createElement("ul");
for (const unit in themeList) {
    let lesson = themeList[unit];
    para.innerHTML = para.innerHTML + '<li>' + lesson '<li>'
}
document.getElementById("myDIV").appendChild(para);
```

this will wrap everything with one `ul` in the outer.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate this answer, but it's very similar to the way I've already implemented it. I was hoping for a pure jquery way to do what I want to do.